# How to handle library breaking changes due to newer TypeScript version

Tags: typescript, semantic-versioning

As a library owner you're eager to provide the best possible features for consumers with the minimal amount of breaking changes. Now as far as I understand your library, if written in TypeScript, depends on a specific version of TS. Say we're on v2.8.x suddenly we'd like to upgrade to TS v3.x.x because of a great new feature.
What happens is that my libraries next release, including the TS dependency bump, would have to be released as a breaking change, following SemVer right?

At the same time the library may be used by JavaScript consumers as well, and they would see no reason for a major bump, because for them, not using type definitions, nothing actually changed. So I feel a bit in a dilemma on what the best practice here would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say we're on v2.8.x suddenly we'd like to upgrade to TS v3.x.x because of a great new feature. What happens is that my libraries next release, including the TS dependency bump, would have to be released as a breaking change, following SemVer right

If your library *type definitions* (the generated `.d.ts` file) *used* to work with TS2.8 and no longer works with TS2.8 then you should release it as major.

Note that most likely this is not going to happen just because you are changing ts version. You have to actively use some new *signature* TS feature in your types to cause this.

> At the same time the library may be used by JavaScript consumers as well, and they would see no reason for a major bump, because for them, not using type definitions, nothing actually changed

Not every breaking change affects *all* people. The JS users can read the changelog and ignore.

Comment: Ok so pretty much what I thought. Just for clarification about new "signature", in my current case I'm leveraging Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions which is new "syntax" not being understood by TS < 3. I guess that's what you meant right?

Comment: @zewa666 yes that is what I meant.